# Is there any jar is available to execute sql queries faster in java?

Tags: java, sql, performance, jar, execution

In java i used the Prepared statement to get the values from Database. Here I used the Index and then I bind the values also, I used the the following query

```
Select pname from project where pid="12547";
```

Like this I need to take around 3000 "pname" from the table project. For this execution it takes more time. Is there any jar is available to execute sql queries faster in java?

Comment: use `select pname from project where pid IN(xx, yy, ...)`?

Comment: There is no such jar.
As suggested in the previous answer, you can look to reduce the number of queries. If for some reason, you need to make these calls sequentially, then you would need to tune DB ( adding index on pid in case its not primary key, etc).

Comment: i need to execute this statement from java and also how to bind the values inside that [IN()] using prepared statement. because the values are **dynamic**..

Answer (score 3):

Why are you executing individual queries for those 3000 pid. If you're sure that you've to execute that many queries that you can switch to any of these that best suits your logic:

```
select pname from project where pid BETWEEN 1000 and 4000;

select pname from project where pid IN (1000, 1001, ...);

select pname from project where pid > 2000 and pid < 5000;
```

You can use these in your where clause to modify your SQL query

```
Operator  Description
=         Equal
<>        Not equal. Note: In some versions of SQL this operator may be written as !=
>         Greater than
<         Less than
>=        Greater than or equal
<=        Less than or equal
BETWEEN   Between an inclusive range
LIKE      Search for a pattern
IN        To specify multiple possible values for a column
```

---

**EDIT**

If your values are dynamic, then

```
String selectSQL = "select pname from project where pid IN(?, ?);";
dbConnection = getDBConnection();
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 2000);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, 5000);

// execute select SQL stetement
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: i need to execute this statement from java and also how to bind the values inside that [IN()] using prepared statement. because the values are **dynamic**..

Comment: I've updated my answer, please refer to it if your values are dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but there u mentioned specifically two question marks. actually that count also must be dynamic, Please try to help me...

Comment: That is the actual code. Those question marks `?` are called positional parameters. Please visit [this](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) tutorial to get some insight about how this thing works.

Comment: Hmm, I already go through it but in my code i used fully dynamic values, so can't pass the values manually.     String sql = " SELECT  [PName] FROM Project  where [Pid]=?";
        preparedstmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
        preparedstmt .setInt(1, PId);  Like wise i used before.

Comment: You can build the "?,?" in a dynamic way using a `StringBuilder` or some guava magic: `Joiner.on(',').join(Collections.nCopies(N, "?"))`